# JSON Exception for Restful Apex Service in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, json, apexrest

Creating a Salesforce REST Api to create a contact when json is posted to it from workbench and my code functions correctly but my test class gives me a weird error that I am not sure how to fix. The code all looks correct to me.

the error is this:

> System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('I' (code 73)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [line:1, column:14]

any help appreciated

Apex Class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ApiClass/*')
global class Rest_APIClass {
    @HttpGet
    global static List<contact> getContactInformation(){
        List<contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, Firstname, LastName, Email, Phone FROM Contact];
        return Contacts;
    }
    
    @HttpPost
    global static void createNewRecord(){
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        String requestBody = req.requestBody.toString();
        
        newContactRequest newContact = (newContactRequest)JSON.deserialize(requestBody, newContactRequest.class);
        
        Contact newContactToInsert = new Contact(FirstName = newContact.firstName, LastName=newContact.lastName, email=newContact.email, phone=newContact.phone);
        
        RestResponse response = RestContext.response;
        response.addHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        
        try{
            insert newContactToInsert;
            
            ContactWrapper wrapper = new ContactWrapper();
            wrapper.firstName = newContact.firstName;
            wrapper.lastName = newContact.lastName;
            wrapper.email = newContact.email;
            wrapper.phone = newContact.phone;
            
           String body = JSON.serializePretty(wrapper);
           response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Body--------> '+ body);
            response.statusCode = 201;
        }catch(exception e){
            RestContext.response.responsebody = Blob.valueOf('{ "Error" : '+ e.getMessage()+' }');
            response.statusCode = 500;
        }
    }
    global class ContactWrapper {
    public String conid{get; set;}
    public String firstName{get; set;}
    public String lastName{get; set;}
    public String email{get; set;}
    public String phone{get; set;}
}
   global class NewContactRequest{
    public String firstName{get; set;}
    public String lastName{get; set;}
    public String email{get; set;}
    public String phone{get; set;}
}
    
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest 
public class Rest_APIClass_Test {
    @testSetup
    static void dataSetup(){
        Contact con = new Contact(firstName = 'Reed', LastName = 'Badman', email='Reed@badman.com', phone='02928343892');
        insert con;
    }
    public static testMethod void testPostive(){
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

        Rest_APIClass.NewContactRequest wrapper = new Rest_APIClass.NewContactRequest();
        wrapper.firstName = 'Reed';
        wrapper.lastName = 'Badman';
        wrapper.email = 'reed@badman.com';
        wrapper.phone = '383478339';
        
        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/ApiClass/';
        req.httpMethod = 'POST';
        req.requestBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serializePretty(wrapper));
        
        RestContext.request = req;
           RestContext.response= res;
        
        Test.startTest();
        Rest_APIClass.createNewRecord();
        Test.stopTest();
        
        Contact newContactCreated = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, email, phone FROM Contact WHERE FirstName = 'Reed'];
        
        Rest_APIClass.ContactWrapper responseBody = (Rest_APIClass.ContactWrapper)JSON.deserialize(res.responseBody.toString(), Rest_APIClass.ContactWrapper.class);
        System.assertEquals(newContactCreated.Id, responseBody.conid);
        System.assertEquals(newContactCreated.FirstName, responseBody.firstName);
        System.assertEquals(newContactCreated.email, responseBody.phone);
        System.assertEquals(201, res.statusCode);
    }
}
```

#update - getting these in logs

looks like this is the output |req---->RestRequest:[headers={}, httpMethod=POST, params={}, remoteAddress=null, requestBody=Blob[107], requestURI=/services/apexrest/ApiClass/, resourcePath=null]
res---->RestResponse:[headers={}, responseBody=null, statusCode=null]

Comment: The first thing to do here would be to print your JSON to the debug log _before_ you try to deserialize it. If there's an issue in the JSON itself, seeing the actual JSON is going to be immensely helpful for figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: @DerekF looks like this is the output

|req---->RestRequest:[headers={}, httpMethod=POST, params={}, remoteAddress=null, requestBody=Blob[107], requestURI=/services/apexrest/ApiClass/, resourcePath=null]

res---->RestResponse:[headers={}, responseBody=null, statusCode=null]

Comment: Rather than answering questions and adding info in the comments, please edit your original question and update it with those answers/that info. This helps keep everything in one place which is better for future readers who either have the same/similar issue, or who can help and are trying to get up to speed. Most people just tack additional info to the end/bottom of their post - often just below an '##### EDIT' or '##### UDPATE'.